# How do I print/use a specific value of a key in mongo shell script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm running the following from the shell;

```
const records = db.issues.find().limit(1);

print('Record:', records);
print('ID:', records.id);
```

It returns one record;

```
Record: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63f94e684902f564f7d418ca"),
    id: 1,
    status: 'New',
    owner: 'Ravan',
    effort: 5,
    created: ISODate("2019-01-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
    due: null,
    title: 'Error in console when clicking Add',
    description: 'Steps to recreate the problem:\n'
  }
]
```

So I thought the last line would produce;

```
ID: 1
```

It just produces **ID:**, without an error, what am I missing?

The next question would then be how do I iterate thru the cursor if multiple records are returned?

Cheers
C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` method returns a cursor that can be iterated over to retrieve each document. In your example, `records` is a cursor that returns an array with one document. To print/use a specific value of a key in the document, you need to access that value using [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) or bracket notation :

```
print('ID:', records[0].id);
```

Iterate through the cursor, you can use a `forEach()` (if multiple records are returned) :

```
const records = db.issues.find();

records.forEach(function(record) {
  print('ID:', record.id);
});
```

Comment: To get the bracket notation to work the following is needed; `const resultsThree = db.issues.find().toArray();
print('resultsThree.ID:', resultsThree[0].id); ` but the forEach() example works, Cheers